# i want to kill the my last sprite while moving and keeping my current sprtie

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

```
import pygame, sys
start = True
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos_x, pos_y):
        super().__init__()
        self.attack_animation = False
        self.sprites = []
        self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load('crossHair.png'))
        self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load('crossHair_2.png'))
        self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load('crossHair_3.png'))
        self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load('crossHair_4.png'))
        self.current_sprite = 0
        self.image = self.sprites[self.current_sprite]
        self.image.set_colorkey('white')
        for items in self.sprites:
            items.set_colorkey('white')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = [pos_x,pos_y]
        

    def attack(self):
        self.attack_animation = True
        self.image.set_colorkey('white')

    def update(self,speed):
        self.image.set_colorkey('white')
        
        self.current_sprite += speed
        if int(self.current_sprite) >= len(self.sprites):
            self.attack_animation = False
            self.current_sprite = 0
        self.image = self.sprites[int(self.current_sprite)]
# General setup
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
# Game Screen
screen_width = 400
screen_height = 400
mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Sprite Animation")

# Creating the sprites and groups


moving_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
while True:
    globals()['mouse'] = pygame.mo[![now this is the problem][1]][1]use.get_pos()
    player = Player(mouse[0],mouse[1])
    moving_sprites.add(player)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            player.attack()
    # Drawing
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    screen.set_colorkey('white')
    moving_sprites.draw(screen)
    moving_sprites.update(0.04)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(120)
```

this is creatiing my player / crossHair every 120th of a second and it leaves behind it's last sprite

now the problem with that is it leaves behind my last sprite and if i put
moving_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
in while loop then it won't animate anybody can solve this pls answer my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the way to animate sprites. Creating a new sprite every frame is bad practice and a waste of performance since all objects have to be recreated. Even more you load the images in the constructor of the `Player` class. If you do this every frame, then every frame the images have to be loaded from the volume and decoded.
Create the sprite **once** before the application loop and change the attributes of the sprite object in the loop. This will give you the best performance:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]
   
    def set_pos(self, pos_x, pos_y):
        self.rect.topleft = (pos_x, pos_y)
```

```py
moving_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player(0, 0)
moving_sprites.add(player)

while True:
    player.set_pos(*pygame.mouse.get_pos())

    # [...]
```